# Is there any way I can groupby and aggregate columns with different conditions?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to track daily and monthly sales data on quantity and value per warehouse.

My monthly data has `['Warehouse','Date','Quantity','Value']`

I am able to use aggregate to sum both quantity and value.

```
df.groupby(['Warehouse']).agg({'Quantity':'sum','Value':'sum'})
```

What is the best way for me to obtain following data in one output?

```
Warehouse Quantity(daily) Quantity(monthly) Value(daily) Value(Monthly)
```

Comment: groupby warehouse and month from date column. then sum of value and quantity like you showed in the code

Comment: hi @SreeramTP, i got Warehouse Month as row, Quantity and Value as column. Not really what i am looking for

Comment: can you post a sample data frame as code (not as image)\]